# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'context' of BaseController

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a base controller which is talking to Entity Framework. I am creating a `dbContext` to talk to entities in base controller. When I inherited my home controller to base controller, it throws the error shown below. Any pointers on this?

Error message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error CS7036
>   There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'context' of 'BaseController.BaseController(ServiceContext)' 
>   Service   \Controllers\HomeController.cs

Code:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
        ServiceContext _baseContext;

        public BaseController(ServiceContext context)
        {
            _baseContext = context;
        }
}
```

My `HomeController` inherits from the base controller.

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    private readonly ServiceContext _context;

    public HomeController(ServiceContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't this be  public `HomeController(ServiceContext context) :base(conext)` ?

Comment: `public HomeController(ServiceContext context) : base(context) { .. }` but why are you setting it in both the `BaseController` and `HomeController`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you properly injecting `ServiceContext` to `HomeController` , it should be something like this :

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected readonly ServiceContext _baseContext;

        public BaseController(ServiceContext context)
        {
            _baseContext = context;
        }
}

public class HomeController : BaseController
        {
            public HomeController(ServiceContext context)
            :base(context)
            {

            }
    }
```

Also since you want to access `ServiceContext` from `HomeController` hence making it `protected`. Also there is no point of setting it in `HomeController`

Answer (score 5):

The base class constructor requires the `context` parameter. So, you should pass one to constructor of the base class:

```
public HomeController(ServiceContext context) : base(context)
{ }
```